# How to fix 'Can't resolve all parameters for ComponentName'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to run `ng serve` command for my angular project. It works, it builds but when I want to access to `localhost:4200` (my local host angular access) the screen is blank and console says:

> Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for
>   CreateContractComponent: (?, ?, ?).

Everything worked before I re-checkout project as a new project to my computer. When I deploy app it perfectly works (For example heroku)

I spent 1 day googling and trying something from the different topics, but still bad. If you need/want more files, let me know.

shortly component code:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ContractService } from '../offer-page/contract.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-contract',
  templateUrl: './create-contract.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-contract.component.css']
})
export class CreateContractComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private contractService: ContractService, private route: ActivatedRoute,private router: Router) {
  }
}
```

`contractService` shortly

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { Contract } from './object-model/contract';

@Injectable()
export class ContractService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }
}
```

What I need is just to run `ng serve` command and be able to work in dev mode. Now it is possible only with deployment (to heroku).

EDIT for request files:

this is my package.json file

```js
{
  "name": "name-of-the-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.9.x",
    "npm": "5.5.x"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "deploy": "git push heroku master",
    "postinstall": "ng build --aot -prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.3",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.15",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "express-basic-auth": "1.2.0",
    "nouislider": "^11.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.4",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

and this is my app.module.ts file

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { ProductsComponent } from './client-page/products/products.component';
import { ClientService } from './client-page/client-offers/client.service';
import { ContractService } from './offer-page/contract.service';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { ClientPageComponent } from './client-page/client-page.component';
import { FirstScreenComponent } from './offer-page/first-screen/first-screen.component';
import { BonusesComponent } from './offer-page/first-screen/bonuses/bonuses.component';
import { DebitCardsComponent } from './offer-page/first-screen/debit-cards/debit-cards.component';
import { ServicesComponent } from './offer-page/first-screen/services/services.component';
import { OfferPageComponent } from './offer-page/offer-page.component';
import { ClientOffersComponent } from './client-page/client-offers/client-offers.component';
import { ProductsService } from './offer-page/first-screen/products.service';
import { ClientPageService } from './client-page/client-page.service';
import { OfferService } from './offer-page/offer.service';
import { RefreshPageService } from './offer-page/first-screen/refresh-page.service';
import { CreateContractComponent } from './create-contract/create-contract.component';
import { AcceptancePageComponent } from './acceptance-page/acceptance-page.component';
import { AttributesComponent } from './offer-page/first-screen/attributes/attributes.component';
import { PricesComponent } from './offer-page/first-screen/prices/prices.component';
import { NamePriceComponent } from './offer-page/first-screen/name-price/name-price.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ClientPageComponent },
  { path: 'createContract/:userId/:offerId', component: CreateContractComponent },
  { path: 'offerPage/:contractId', component: OfferPageComponent },
  { path: 'contractCreated/:contractId', component: AcceptancePageComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    ProductsComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    ClientPageComponent,
    FirstScreenComponent,
    BonusesComponent,
    DebitCardsComponent,
    ServicesComponent,
    OfferPageComponent,
    ClientOffersComponent,
    CreateContractComponent,
    AcceptancePageComponent,
    AttributesComponent,
    PricesComponent,
    NamePriceComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [ ClientService, ContractService,
    ProductsService, ClientPageService, OfferService,
    RefreshPageService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: are you adding the `ContractService` to the `AppModule`'s providers attribute?

Comment: contract serivce needs to be providedIn Root @Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })

Comment: would help to see your package.json and your app.module.ts

Comment: As you requested I added files.

Comment: `(?, ?, ?)` does not make sense to me, because the last two parameters are well known types for Angular. Are you creating this component dynamically?

Comment: constructor(private contractService: ContractService, private route: ActivatedRoute,private router: Router) {
  }

Can you tell me what are you injecting for the Second Parameter ?

Comment: Yes, it should be created dynamically.

Comment: The second parameter is ActivatedRoute from '@angular/router' later used for navigate to another location

Answer (score 0):

Well after check a lot of commits I found the problem. I miss this line in this file

> src/polyfills.ts

```js
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```

Description why it is needed:

> Evergreen browsers require these. Used for reflect-metadata in JIT.

But don`t know, what does it do but it works!